# Does ApplicationSignInManager retain a list of successful logins?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using `ApplicationSignInManager` to authenticate user logins (see code below).
What I want to do next is prevent duplicate users logging in at the same time, and also to prevent more than 10 users logging in concurrently.

I could maintain my own collection of which users are currently logged in and refer to this, but I was wondering if `ApplicationSignInManager` offers any functionality like this automatically?

```
// GET: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}


public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set { _signInManager = value; }
}

//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationSignInManager` does not do any counting and doesnot internally keep track of signed-in users. All it does is creating authentication cookie for the user.

You can prevent concurrent loggins by resetting Security Stamp for a user just before you create a cookie:

```
var loggedinUser = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
if (loggedinUser != null)
{
    // Now user have entered correct username and password.
    // Time to change the security stamp
    await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(loggedinUser.Id);
}

// do sign-in AFTER we have done the update of the security stamp, so the new stamp goes into the cookie
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

More on that in my [blog](http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/09/prevent-multiple-logins-in-asp-net-identity/)

To have a limited number of users logged in - you'll have to implement your own counting. But you'll face a problem with deciding what "logged in" actually means. I.e. does having an open browser tab counts as logged in? what if that tab was not used for 5 minutes? 10? 2 hours? What if user closed that tab without hitting "Log-out" - cookie is still there, it is probably not expired, but your app never received a message of user going offline.

You'll need to make these decisions yourself as there is nothing in the framework that will provide you with this functionality.